# Optimizing python code by using cython

Tags: string, cython

I would like to optimize a code in [Python](https://www.python.org/) in order to increase a speed of string processing and was wondering if someone can help.

I did some tests in [Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but I am not particularly happy with the results. I am wondering if string processing can be even optimized or perhaps I have not created a proper code in [Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). In the first case, interating over list of strings and a simple assignment to a variable was about 5 times faster on average. In the other case, where I included searching for a substring, there was no speed increase at all.

[TL;DR]

I have a large corpora which I need to process. Currently, in pure python, I iterate over list of strings searching for a substring and filter out those elements (main strings) which do not contain a given substring. I have created a couple of for loops and was hoping for a significant speed increase after converting a code to [Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

First, I tested how fast would a simple iteration over two lists of strings be when strings are assigned to a variable:

Results:

```
[Cython][1]: 0.45067 sec
[Python][2]: 2.09907 sec
[Cython][1] approximately 4.5 times faster than [Python][2]
```

Code in [Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
def start(itsstr, tokens):
    cdef size_t s
    cdef size_t t
    cdef size_t ns = len(itsstr)
    cdef size_t nt = len(tokens)
    cdef unicode x
    for s in xrange(ns):
        for t in xrange(nt):
            x = itsstr[s]
```

[Python](https://www.python.org/)

```
def start(itsstr, tokens):
    for s in itsstr:
        for t in tokens:
            x = s
```

The current main code in [Python](https://www.python.org/) searches for a substrings. I tested a speed increase against searching for a substring in [Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). The results are following:

Results:

```
[Cython][1]: 7.13278 sec
[Python][2]: 8.7094 sec
[Cython][1] 1.2 times faster than [Python][2]
```

Code in [Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
def start(itsstr, tokens):
    cdef size_t s
    cdef size_t t
    cdef size_t ns = len(itsstr)
    cdef size_t nt = len(tokens)
    cdef unicode x
    for s in xrange(ns):
        for t in xrange(nt):
            if tokens[t] in itsstr[s]:
                x = itsstr[s]
```

Code in [Python](https://www.python.org/)

```
def start(itsstr, tokens):
    for s in itsstr:
        for t in tokens:
            if t in s:
                x = s
```

As you can see there is no really any speed increase.

I have been thinking about what I could do at this point? I am not experienced in [Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I have a good experience in C/C++ , though.

Thanks

Comment: 80% of your running time is spent in `t in s`. Cython cannot help you with that - there is no magic. what is the type of `s`? I would start by making `s` a `set`, if this it is not already is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In Python, `s` is a `str` type, a unicode in Python 3. I iterate over a list of `str` objects.